# How to merge content from two .doc files into one using JavaScript in LWC or Apex

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, files, merge, js

I have an input type file which takes two .doc files. Then I need to merge content from this files into one .doc file and download it. I supposed it is needed to read files as ArrayBuffer and then combine and convert using window.btoa(). But nothing good happens. Hope you'll give me a hand

My HTML

```
<template>
      <input
            onchange={filesLoaded}
            type="file"
            multiple>
</template>
```

My JS

```
   async filesLoaded(event) {
        let file1 = event.target.files[0];
        let file2 = event.target.files[1];
        let reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function(e) {

        };

        Promise.all([file1.arrayBuffer(), file2.arrayBuffer()])
                .then(buffers => {
                    console.log(buffers[0]);
                    console.log(buffers[1]);

                    var b1 = new Uint8Array(buffers[0]);
                    var b2 = new Uint8Array(buffers[1]);

                    let binary = '';
                    const bytes = new Uint8Array([...b1,...b2]);
                    const len = bytes.byteLength;

                    for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                        binary += String.fromCharCode(bytes[i]);
                    }
                    let file = window.btoa(binary);
                    const url = 'data:application/msword;base64,' + file;

                    console.log(url);



                })
                .catch(console.error);

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately merging two doc files isn't that simple because it's a specific format with some headers. Combining the two files will only create a corrupt file.

You'll need a library that can parse the doc format and do a proper merge. I don't think that there's any such lib in JS for the browser (maybe in Node.js) or Apex. You'll likely need some sort of integration with another system.